# Deface not working from engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, deface

I'm trying to use [deface gem](https://github.com/spree/deface) as a way to overwrite my core app views from a modules (engines). Deface works just great if i'm creating a `.deface` files in `core_app/app/overrides/*`. However, when i want to use it from my engine (by creating exact same files in `core_app/engines/some_engine/app/overrides/*`) it's not working anymore.

My engine is a "clean" engine created using `rails plugin new` command, trying to use deface was the first thing i've implemented there so there is nothing which can interfere with deface. At least from the plugin point of view.

I'm including my engine like this (in core app gemfile): `gem 'some_engine', path: 'engines/some_engine'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by the fact that i have used `rails plugin new my_plugin_name` without the

```
--mountable
```

flag. Add this flag and everything will work just fine.